# Serving resources from consistent URL

Tags: product-images, frontend

I made a e-commerce website using magento 1.9.2.2 (CE) ( currently running on shared hosting ) ( current php version : 5.6 ).

url : https://i-ranu.com

when i checked the website performance on gtmetrix it shows recommendation of serving resources from a consistent url.

herewith provide details what it shows.
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 1 request(s) and 25.1KiB.

https://www.i-ranu.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/300x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/d/-/d-138_cruze_lemon_blue.jpg
https://www.i-ranu.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/300x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/d/-/d-138_cruze_lemon_blue.jpg
The following resources have identical contents, but are served from different URLs. Serve these resources from a consistent URL to save 1 request(s) and 23.0KiB.

https://www.i-ranu.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/300x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/d/-/d-147cruzeblue.jpg
https://www.i-ranu.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/thumbnail/300x/17f82f742ffe127f42dca9de82fb58b1/d/-/d-147cruzeblue.jpg

am unable to figure out how to solve this issue as in this case both images are loaded from single https url but one is small image and other as thumbnail.

can anyone help please how to make it load only one image.
[image]

Comment: Do you need to have the thumbnail?  Also, I realize it may be redundant if you don't need it, but 23KiB is not that large yet it is excessive if you do not need it.  For speed I recommend updating your PHP to 7.1 for performance.  Inchoo has a module for Magento 1.9 to allow for PHP upgrades to increase performance.